# Ubuntu freezing during installation

Tags: installation, boot, bios

I planned on upgrading my PC to Ubuntu from Windows 7, and erasing Windows 7 completely. I ran through the installation, choosing to erase my current OS and install Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

After a while, the installer froze my PC completely, something I thought would be normal, so I waited. I figured it would be finished by the time I had gotten back, so I went out for dinner, and to visit some open house art gallery with a friend, and returned about 5 or 6 hours later to see the screen has not changed.

I rebooted my computer to find out that the BIOS and such isn't being read off the flash drive on start-up, but also that my PC has neither Ubuntu or Windows 7 installed.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried holding down `F6` during a cold boot, select language, then `F6` again to get the options on the lower right to show up. Select `nolapic`, `EDD=On`, and `nomodeset`. Press ENTER. Next, down arrow to the second line which is the Install line. ***DO NOT PRESS ENTER OR A LEFT OR RIGHT ARROW!!*** Now back space and delete quiet and splash with `nomodeset`. Now press ENTER. The installation will begin and if it hangs up now, you will see what was the last process/script that completed.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the CD is faulty, try burning another and installing from it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

- If you have a motherboard with UEFI, turn it off.
- Make sure USB or CD/DVD (depends on what you will use), is the first boot device.
- If you have burned a disc make sure its working, or burn another one, checking for errors and at a slow speed.
- If you are using a pen drive, generate the image again, using UNetbootin.